# Are there any photos of the Martian terminator from low Mars orbit?

Tags: mars, photography, mars-orbiters

This photo of Earth was taken from the ISS, an [altitude of 211 nautical miles](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap130406.html).[image]

This photo of Mars was [taken 71,000 kilometers above Mars (about 10 Mars diameters away)](https://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/mars/northern-summer-global-view.html).

[image]

Are there any images of the Mars terminator similar to the first image, of Earth?

This image of Mars is [simulated](https://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/mars/gale-on-the-terminator.html),

[image]

> PERSPECTIVE VIEW OF MARS: GALE ON THE TERMINATOR
>   In this simulated view of Mars, Gale crater

Answer (score 3):

You can find hundreds if not thousands of such photos by using the Planetary Data System search engine. Although most are not that "pretty".

Here's a sample [query](https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov/search/?fq=TARGET%3Amars&fq=ATLAS_SPACECRAFT_NAME%3A%22mars%20reconnaissance%20orbiter%22&q=terminator) for Mars, Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter, and Terminator.

One of the images returned has this label

```
DATA_SET_ID                    = "MRO-M-HIRISE-2-EDR-V1.0"
DATA_SET_NAME                  = "MRO MARS HIGH RESOLUTION IMAGING SCIENCE
                                 EXPERIMENT EDR V1.0"
PRODUCER_INSTITUTION_NAME      = "UNIVERSITY OF ARIZONA"
PRODUCER_ID                    = "UA"
PRODUCER_FULL_NAME             = "ALFRED MCEWEN"
OBSERVATION_ID                 = "PSP_009714_3065"
MRO:COMMANDED_ID               = "PSP_009714_3065"
PRODUCT_ID                     = "PSP_009714_3065_BG12_0"
PRODUCT_VERSION_ID             = "1"
SOURCE_FILE_NAME               = "4A_01_4897CA6500_04_0_01.DAT"
INSTRUMENT_HOST_NAME           = "MARS RECONNAISSANCE ORBITER"
INSTRUMENT_HOST_ID             = "MRO"
INSTRUMENT_NAME                = "HIGH RESOLUTION IMAGING SCIENCE EXPERIMENT"
INSTRUMENT_ID                  = "HIRISE"
TARGET_NAME                    = "MARS"
MISSION_PHASE_NAME             = "PRIMARY SCIENCE PHASE"
ORBIT_NUMBER                   = 9714
RATIONALE_DESC                 = "Sample - northern terminator"
SOFTWARE_NAME                  = "HiRISE_Observation v2.10.4 (2.44 2007/06/13
                                 01:05:33)"
FLIGHT_SOFTWARE_VERSION_ID     = "IE_FSW_V4"
```

and looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image of Mars from an altitude of about 200 statute miles, I suppose. Unfortunately I don't know its precise altitude and which probe shot it. There are hardly descriptions of it.

[image: Mars and its atmosphere]

Comment: Can you annotate the image to show the terminator?  The question asks for a picture of the terminator.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't know, there's little description of that image coursing throughout the web.

Comment: [National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/news/2015/3/150305-mars-ocean-water-map-space-science/) says this is a Viking image and [Universe Today](https://www.universetoday.com/14979/mars-radiation1/amp/) says "...taken by the Viking 1 orbiter in June 1976." [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2017/03/03/nasa-discovers-how-mars-lost-its-atmosphere/#40214569326a) says "Image credit: NASA/Viking 1".  While this is not really an image of the terminator, it's getting close; at the bottom right we see  that the sides of tall features facing us are dark.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [Which Viking-1 orbiter photo is this? When was it taken and what part of Mars is shown?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/42069/12102)

Comment: @uhoh Thank you for asking, you lifted the riddle. I knew the image is quite old. We see the large shadows of the mountains so the terminator is obviously close as you say.

Comment: and it's just [been answered](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43566/12102)