# Which Viking-1 orbiter photo is this? When was it taken and what part of Mars is shown?

Tags: mars, identify-this-object, photography, viking

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/42060/12102) to *Are there any photos of the Martian terminator from low Mars orbit?* includes (without credit) what looks like an oft-repeated photo of Mars. A [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/42053/are-there-any-photos-of-the-martian-terminator-from-low-mars-orbit#comment137612_42060) written from reverse image searching suggests it's from [Viking-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_1) in 1976.

> [National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/news/2015/3/150305-mars-ocean-water-map-space-science/) says this is a Viking image and [Universe Today](https://www.universetoday.com/14979/mars-radiation1/amp/) says "...taken by the Viking 1 orbiter in June 1976." [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2017/03/03/nasa-discovers-how-mars-lost-its-atmosphere/#40214569326a) says "Image credit: NASA/Viking 1".  While this is not really an image of the terminator, it's getting close; at the bottom right we see  that the sides of tall features facing us are dark.

Since it's taken from orbit I've gone to https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/Help/PIADetQuery.html
and selected "Viking-1 orbiter" from the `Search for Images by Spacecraft` option. The resulting search query https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/spacecraft/Viking%2BOrbiter%2B1 yields thumbnails of 87 images which doesn't seem include this one. Then again 87 sounds low.

**Question:** Which Viking-1 orbiter photo is this? When was it taken and what part of Mars is shown?

With the time and identity of (at least some of) the features in the image known, I'd like to try to figure out the foreground's proximity to the terminator, possibly using the reconstructed trajectory in JPL's [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) as well since it includes a model for coordinates on planets and their rotation.

---

[image: unidentified image presumably of Mars taken by the Viking-1 orbiter circa 1976] click for full size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viking Orbiter "violet-light" picture 34A13, it shows

> the region east and northeast of the Argyre basin during winter in the
>   southern hemisphere. (a) Most of the snow-covered Argyre basin is shown. This was taken just after the winter solstice when solar heating was minimal.

Further down it says the location is 47° S, 22° W

[image]

I found it in [NASA-SP-441](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19810003458.pdf) *Viking Orbiter Views of Mars* p. 144 where it is shown in black & white. Some pictures in this document are in color. I suspect the linked image may have been re-processed more recently although I haven't found direct evidence of that. I read that [this fellow](https://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2018/0507-refreshing-the-viking-orbiter.html) was doing some of that work.

It's in the JPL PDS Image Atlas [here](https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov/search/?fq=ATLAS_SPACECRAFT_NAME%3A%22viking%20orbiter%201%22&q=f034a13). You can download a .img file but I don't know how to open that kind of file.  The label there says the image time is **1976-07-24T10:35:26Z**.

[image]

Just for fun, here's a similar view from Google Earth's Mars globe showing the chain of four large craters, which TIL are [Lohse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lohse_(Martian_crater)), [Helmholtz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_(Martian_crater)), [Wirtz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtz_(crater)), and [Galle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galle_(Martian_crater)) craters. At least one of those names resonates with me :)

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, thanks, and way more info than I'd expected to find! But now I'm surprised to see that I can't find the Viking orbiter in Horizons so I've asked [Locations of the terminator on Mars' surface on 1976-07-24T10:35:26Z?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/42087/12102)

Comment: and it's just [been answered](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43566/12102)